# Selecting values from a table that are connected to only one value in another table inbetween by two one-to-many tables

Tags: java, sqlite

As an example of the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE group (group_id int primary key, group_name string unique)
CREATE TABLE gitems (gitem_id int primary key, ...)
CREATE TABLE group_gitem (group_id int foreign key, gitem_id int foreign key)
CREATE TABLE object_gitem (gitem_id int foreign key, object_id string foreign key)
CREATE TABLE object (object_id string primary key, ...)
```

I would like to select all object_ids that appear in one specific group but not object_ids that appear in multiple groups. I have tried the following query but it isn't doing what I hoped it would and actually returns nothing.

```
SELECT object_id, COUNT(group_id) AS link_count FROM group 
LEFT JOIN group_gitem ON group_gitem.group_id = group.group_id 
LEFT JOIN object_gitem ON object_gitem.gitem_id = group_gitem.gitem_id 
GROUP BY object_id 
HAVING link_count <= 1 AND group_id = 0
```

I am planning to use the object_ids to delete their respective jpg images on the disk for example `aBjf9k4d9l.jpg` would link to object_id value `aBjf9k4d9l`. Then I plan to delete the group and all items related while keeping objects that still are linked to another group even if it exists in the one I plan on deleting from the database.

Comment: Is it java related ? I mean do you want it SQL only on with Java code ?

Comment: Well I guess it isn't completely java related but I am using the java-sqlite library. I was looking for the SQL only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using set operations is often simpler than joins:

```sql
WITH og AS (
  SELECT object_id,
         group_id
  FROM object_gitem
  JOIN group_gitem USING (gitem_id)
)
SELECT object_id
FROM object
WHERE object_id     IN (SELECT object_id
                        FROM og
                        WHERE group_id =  0)
  AND object_id NOT IN (SELECT object_id
                        FROM og
                        WHERE group_id <> 0);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I wouldn't have thought to have done it like that.